# How to remove referenced from List of Figures with app cite in article class. Also how can I centre captions?

Tags: table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment, captions, apacite

How can I get the list of figures to not show the in caption references but still show them in caption? also, how can I center the caption? New to Latex all help is appreciated.

Heres my Preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[toc]{appendix}
\usepackage[margin=1.0in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {figures/} }
\usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{titlesec}
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
    \titleformat{\paragraph}
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
    \titlespacing*{\paragraph}
    {0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}

And Figure Matter:

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
    \includegraphics{"Figure 1".png}\\
    \caption{Illuminated manuscript miniature of a priest graffitiing a consecration mark onto a church entrance with a hammer and chisel - later alter in the Reformation to imitate a crosier and sceptre \protect\cite[693]{Breviary1330}.}
    \label{fig1}
\centreing
\end{figure}
```

Comment: `\caption` usually has an optional argument for the LoF: `\caption[short title for LoF]{long caption with \cite{foo}}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! @moewe’s comment answer the first of your questions, but please note that you shouldn’t ask two questions in the same post: move the other question to a new one.

Comment: Captions less than one line are automatically centered (unless you turn singlelinecheck off).  The easiest way to format captions is to use the caption package (justification=centering).